# External Yeti Michrophone not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, sound, 18.04

I have external Usb Microphone by Yeti. With every Ubuntu upgrade it takes me hours to set it up. However, after upgrade to 18.04 the microphone is not detected at all.

The result of **dmesg** is:

```
[ 1723.642721] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[ 1723.770713] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1724.006692] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1724.242693] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[ 1724.370702] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1724.606727] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1724.714717] usb usb3-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 1725.366737] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[ 1725.366894] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1725.574909] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1725.782715] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 28, error -71
[ 1725.910731] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 1725.910884] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1726.118876] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1726.326694] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 29, error -71
[ 1726.326786] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Any ideas how it can be solved are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

lo,

Had some troubles too with my external microphone (not USB but with micro in-plug), this one:

[Philips SBC MM300](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21K14DLmSQL._SS500_.jpg)

Looked around on the Net and wrote a small bash script with my modest knowledge (see further on).

The number '1' loads microphone module and the number '0' resets sound.

As mentioned in the script, 'Pavucontrol', should be installed but that should be alright on Ubuntu 18.04 (I use Linux Mint 19 Xfce myself).

Give the script Rights Everyone in all cases (maybe easiest by rightclicking the script).

To reload it, the name of the script file has to be the exact name as the file name at the bottom of the script. In the example: 'Microphonesound_On-Off.sh'.

Put the script somewhere and possibly shortcut it to your pc desktop (easy with PCman FM file explorer). Start by clicking or rightclicking and 'Open in terminal'.

If you still experience trouble after activating the micro sound module, go to your volume settings and check under 'Configuration' tab if 'Analog Stereo Duplex' is selected under 'Built-in Audio'.
Test your Volume settings in general after having activated the microphone sound with the script.

Different systems, different configurations. But it gives an idea.

Finally the script (copy all the text until 'Microphonesound_On-Off.sh' and save as 'Microphonesound_On-Off.sh'):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "MICROPHONE SOUND ON OR OFF"

# Requires Pavucontrol

echo

echo "Sound On = 1, Sound Off = 0 (zero):"

echo

read INPUT

if [ $INPUT == '1' ] # space before/after brackets!

then

echo 

sleep 2 # required to load module

pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=10 # microphone sound On

echo "Micro sound On!"

elif [ $INPUT == '0' ]

then

echo

pulseaudio -k # reset all sound to default

echo "Micro sound Off!"

else

echo

echo "Wrong Input."
echo "Type 1 or 0."

fi

echo

echo "Enter = Reload"

echo

read

./Microphonesound_On-Off.sh
```